# How to show ads on TVOS using AVInterstitialTimeRange?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, interstitial, avplayerviewcontroller

When playing a movie, I would like to show some ads using AVInterstitialTimeRange. I was able to create the "dots" on the progress bar when playing the movie, but how do I actually present the ads?

so far this is my code to present the ads.

```
 NSArray *adBreaks = result.adBreaks;

  _player.player.currentItem.interstitialTimeRanges = adBreaks;
  NSMutableArray *adBreaksCMTime = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for(AdBreak *brk in adBreaks) {
  CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake([brk adBreakTime], 1);
  CMTime durationCM = CMTimeMake([brk adBreakDuration], 1);

  AVInterstitialTimeRange *adTimeRange = [[AVInterstitialTimeRange alloc]initWithTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(seekingCM, durationCM)];
                    [adBreaksCMTime addObject:adTimeRange];
                }
 _player.player.currentItem.interstitialTimeRanges = adBreaksCMTime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quoth the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVKit/Reference/AVInterstitialTimeRange_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVInterstitialTimeRange) (emphasis added):

> An `AVInterstitialTimeRange` object ***identifies*** a time range in an audiovisual presentation as interstitial content, such as advertisements or legal notices. By associating interstitial time ranges with an `AVPlayerItem` object you present with the `AVPlayerViewController` class, you can customize or restrict the presentation of interstitial content. For example, you can allow the user to easily skip advertisements or prohibit skipping of a legal notice.

Translation: you don't use this API to *present* ads. You present ads as part of the same media stream as your content, or perhaps through a composition of several sources played through one `AVPlayerItem`.

If, once you're already presenting interstitial content, you want the time ranges corresponding to such content to be clearly marked in the UI (for easy skipping or to prohibit skipping), you can use `AVInterstitialTimeRange` to mark them.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could toggle between the ad and the movie using one av player item?

Comment: That's what `AVVideoComposition` and friends are for. See the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1) to get started.

Comment: Hey I am struggling with that too. My ads are stitched in the stream so if content length was 50 minutes after adding 10 minutes of ads the length will be 60 minutes. But when I add these ranges they don't appear on proper places do you have any idea ?